# How do I use Asp MVC Url Helpers to generate RESTful links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to use Html.ActionLink to generate a link with in this form:

/Action/Model/Id/Parameter1/Parameter2

I've used:
`<%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Model", new { id = var, parament1=var1 }, null) %>` 
but it always ends up looking like /Action/Model/Id?parameter1=variable

I've seen similar questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I can't find a solution that works/makes sense.  Any help would be appreciated.

@John: I have the following route registered: `routes.MapRoute("Alternate","{controller}/{action}/{id}/{Heading}", new { controller = "Designation", action = "Details", id = "", Heading = "" }`

I then have the following code in my view: `<%= Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Model", new { Id = model.Id, Heading = model.Heading }, null) %>`

I get /Model/Action/Id?Heading=var1  I want it as /Model/Action/Id/var1

ANSWER:  I added the following route to my global.asax.cs file and the links generated correctly.
 routes.MapRoute("Something", "MyModel/MyAction/{Id}/{Heading}", new { controller = "MyModel", action = "MyAction", id = "", heading = "" }, new { controller = @"[^.]*" });

Comment: Did you register your routes in the Global.ASAX to support /Action/Controller/Id/Parameter1/Parameter2?  By Default the route registered in Global.ASAX is /Controller/Action/id and all other parameters entered are in the QueryString.